# Create a schema like an existing schema

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-10g

I have a existing schema in my database called SCOTT, how can I create a new schema with exactly the same privileges which SCOTT schema is having?

Is there any create like or some command to create schema like SCOTT?

Thanks

Comment: That quoted answer is too complicated. The simpliest way is to `expdp \'/ as sysdba\' schemas=scott` and `impdp \'/ as sysdba\' remap_schema=scott:brown`

Comment: You're welcome. Just check object level grants after such cloning.